# Create a spreadsheet-like cell grid on a browser

Tags: python-3.x, spreadsheet

I want to create a spreadsheet-like form on a browser/frame. The form will create a grid of cells just like a spreadsheet where user can input data that I will save as a xls/csv, etc. I do not need any of the spreadsheet functionality (formula, reference to another cell, etc.) I do not need other convenience like dragging mouse to copy the same value in other cells.

Does any such *freeware* facility or library exist? Implementation in Python will be desirable, but is not necessary. I looked into [Handsontable](https://handsontable.com/) but unfortunately that is not free. I do not intend to use any form of gsheet or office360 for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many searches, found this excellent round up of the solutions by Roberto Bicchierai. Writing it here so that other folks with similar questions can benefit from it: [Eltit Golb](https://roberto.open-lab.com/2010/01/30/javascript-grid-editor-i-want-to-be-excel/).